# Manually expire a token in google api

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api

It seems that I need to wait for 60 minutes in order for my google token to expire. I am trying to test if my code on how to refresh my token is working, I don't have time to wait for 60 minutes just to test if it's working.

Is there a way to expire a google token manually so that i can test if my refresh token code is working?

Answer (score 5):

By revoking access_token, you revoke the refresh_token too, [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) :

> The token can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, **the refresh token will also be revoked**.

So there is no way to expire access_token and keep the refresh_token.

But you can test if the refresh_token is working with no need to expire access_token (you can have many access_token).

Else you can just check a status of your access_token on this url :
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

And according to the return you refresh or not your access_token.

Answer (score -1):

The URL `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}` should revoke it. [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)

If you're using the PHP gapi client, you should be able to call the function `$client->revokeToken(token)` to have the client make that call for you.

Comment: Just if someone is looking, this works, but will invalidate both access and refresh token. :)